# Why I can't post my Form Data to my HttpPost method on C# MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have a trouble when i post my form data to my httppost method. 
when i send my data to the view, it has the value and the value is displayed well. but when i want to save it(post it to the httppost method), the httpost method received a null object.

here is my code for the httpget method and httppost method

```
namespace DeviceBuilder.Controllers
{
public class WebServiceController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /WebService/

    komponenClient client = new komponenClient();
    debuDBDataContext debuDB = new debuDBDataContext();

    public ActionResult ReqWebService(string devname, string compname)
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Choose your Device's Component";
        var alljenis=client.loadJKbyDevCom(devname, compname);
        IList<JeniskomponenModels> listjenis = new List<JeniskomponenModels>();
        if (alljenis != null)
        {
            foreach (var datajenis in alljenis)
            {
                listjenis.Add(new JeniskomponenModels
                {
                    id = datajenis.id,
                    device = datajenis.device,
                    component = datajenis.component,
                    name = datajenis.name,
                    brand = datajenis.brand,
                    information = datajenis.information,
                    price = datajenis.price,
                    stock = datajenis.stock,
                });
            }
        }
        return View(listjenis);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Build(IList<ComponentModels> model)
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Saved";
        BuildRequest BR = new BuildRequest();
        BuildRequestDetail BRD = new BuildRequestDetail();
        int totalharga=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++)
        {
            BR.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            BR.Status = "Saved";
            BR.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            debuDB.BuildRequests.InsertOnSubmit(BR);
            debuDB.SubmitChanges();

            for (int j = 0; j < model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (model.ElementAt(i).SlistJenis.SelectedValue.ToString() == model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).name)
                {
                    BRD.BuildID = BR.Id;
                    BRD.Device = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).device;
                    BRD.JenisBrand = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).brand;
                    BRD.JenisInformasi = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).information;
                    BRD.Component = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).component;
                    BRD.JenisName = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).name;
                    BRD.JenisHarga = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).price;
                    BRD.JenisStock = model.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis.ElementAt(j).stock;
                    totalharga += BRD.JenisHarga;

                    debuDB.BuildRequestDetails.InsertOnSubmit(BRD);
                    debuDB.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }

            var update = (from buildrequest in debuDB.BuildRequests where buildrequest.Id == BRD.Id select new{
                        username=buildrequest.UserName, status=buildrequest.Status, 
                        datetime=buildrequest.DateTime}).First();

            BR.UserName = update.username;
            BR.Status = update.status;
            BR.DateTime = update.datetime;
            BR.Total = totalharga;

            debuDB.BuildRequests.InsertOnSubmit(BR);
            debuDB.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return View(model);

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Build(string devname)
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Choose your Device's Component";
        ViewBag.Device = devname;
        var all = client.loadJKbyDev(devname);

        IList<JeniskomponenModels> listjenis = new List<JeniskomponenModels>();
        IList<ComponentModels> listcomp = new List<ComponentModels>();

        string compname = ""; int alreadycomp = 0, alreadyat = -1;
        if (all != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < all.Count(); i++)
            {
                compname = all.ElementAt(i).component;
                for (var j = 0; j < listcomp.Count(); j++)
                {
                    if (listcomp.ElementAt(j).Name == compname)
                    {
                        alreadycomp = 1; alreadyat = j;
                        //already at nya menuju ke 0 makanya naman nya snap dragon. buat ke yang ke tiga, pasti bisa
                    }
                }
                if (alreadycomp == 1)
                {
                    listcomp.ElementAt(alreadyat).IlistJenis.Add(new JeniskomponenModels
                    {
                        brand = all.ElementAt(i).brand,
                        component = all.ElementAt(i).component,
                        device = all.ElementAt(i).device,
                        information = all.ElementAt(i).information,
                        name = all.ElementAt(i).name,
                        price = all.ElementAt(i).price,
                        stock = all.ElementAt(i).stock,
                        id = all.ElementAt(i).id,
                    });
                    listcomp.ElementAt(alreadyat).SlistJenis = new SelectList((IEnumerable<JeniskomponenModels>)listcomp.ElementAt(alreadyat).IlistJenis,"Id","Name");
                }
                else if (alreadycomp == 0)
                {
                    listcomp.Add(new ComponentModels
                    {
                        DevName=all.ElementAt(i).device,
                        Name=all.ElementAt(i).component,
                        Supplier="e-Kelontong",
                        IlistJenis=new List<JeniskomponenModels>(){new JeniskomponenModels{
                            brand = all.ElementAt(i).brand,
                            component = all.ElementAt(i).component,
                            device = all.ElementAt(i).device,
                            information = all.ElementAt(i).information,
                            name = all.ElementAt(i).name,
                            price = all.ElementAt(i).price,
                            stock = all.ElementAt(i).stock,
                            id = all.ElementAt(i).id,
                        }},
                    });
                    listcomp.Last().SlistJenis = new SelectList((IEnumerable<JeniskomponenModels>)listcomp.Last().IlistJenis,"Id","Name");
                }
            }
        }


        return View(listcomp);
    }
}
```

}

and here is my view

```
@model IList<DeviceBuilder.Models.ComponentModels>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Build";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.message</h2>
</hgroup>

<section class="contact">
<header>
    <h3>@ViewBag.Device</h3>
</header>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Build","WebService",FormMethod.Post)){<table>
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div>
                   @Html.LabelFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).Name)
               </div>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div>
                   @Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).DevID)
                   @Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).DevName)
                   @Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).Id)
                   @Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).IlistJenis)
                   @Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).Supplier)
               </div>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div>
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).SlistJenis,Model.ElementAt(i).SlistJenis,"Select")
               </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save">}</section>
```

can anybody help me to pass my selected value back to the httppost method??

for additional information, this is the value from the form data that has been selected but not posted to the httppost method. I searched it with google chrome

```
-General
Remote Address:[::1]:62870
Request URL:http: //localhost:62870/WebService/Build
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
-Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:12139
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 22 May 2015 04:54:15 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcS3VsaWFoXFNlbWVzdGVyIDRcUFJPS09GXERldmljZUJ1aWxkZXJcRGV2aWNlQnVpbGRlclxXZWJTZXJ2aWNlXEJ1aWxk?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:id-ID,id;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:315
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:62870
Origin:http: //localhost:62870
Referer:http: //localhost:62870/WebService/Build?devname=Handphone
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
DevID:0
DevName:Handphone
Id:0
IlistJenis:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DeviceBuilder.Models.JeniskomponenModels]
Supplier:e-Kelontong
SlistJenis:3
DevID:0
DevName:Handphone
Id:0
IlistJenis:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DeviceBuilder.Models.JeniskomponenModels]
Supplier:e-Kelontong
SlistJenis:2
Name    
Build   
1 requests ❘ 12.2 KB transferred ❘ Finish: 13 ms ❘ DOMContentLoaded: 42 ms ❘ Load: 36 ms
```

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(M=>M.ElementAt(i).DevID)` does not generate the correct `name` attribute to post back to a collection. It needs to be `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].DevID)` But why on earth do you have all those hidden inputs? Use a view model!

Comment: And you `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method makes no sense at all. `SlistJenis` is a complex object and you cannot bind a dropdown to a complex object (html has no concept of what a c# class is. You need to bind to a value property (`int` or `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am new to this whole thing.

Comment: No kidding :) Start by changing the hidden inputs to `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].DevID)` so that at least you can see how those properties will be now correctly bound.

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please help with real code? i want to make a dynamic drop down list. dynamic means the select list item of that drop down list depends on how many data is available. and i want to make total of the drop down list created is dynamic too. thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I facing this type of problem too with my MVC 4 web sites which was not posting in one of the page.  After spending many days of my short life in trying to solve this with many posts and googling. After trying many answers of theses posts without success, i have decided to go deeply to understand the reasons which don't allow my form to be posted. I have take look in internet and finally decide to install Fiddle (this free tool of Eric Lawrence allows to capture any transaction between tne client and the server) by using it to post the page which contained the problem, the request has aborted due to the difference between the size send by he request and the actual size of request's headers. By continuing googling, it arise that this was due to the maxrequestlenght of the web config file which by default can not allows you to post a page which has some very high size(was page was sending most than 25 pictures of differents size to the server with the post). so i have override this default value in my web config file with this line of code in system. web

```
    <system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" maxRequestLength="1000000" />
  .......
 .......
</system.web>
```

With this code the max length of a post for any given page is 1G size. By doing like this and trying to post my page again, i have success the posting after this.